# Copy files from Azure blob to Sharepoint folder using Microsoft Flow

Tags: azure, sharepoint, blob, power-automate

I want to copy files from Azure blob storage to SharePoint Folder using Microsoft Flow. I have tried several times and the flow always fail when its running.

I have attached the flow that I'm currently trying to execute:

[image]

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Would you kindly share some more details about whatever you have tried. Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide more details or screenshots of your requirements and your microsoft flow ?

Comment: Are you trying to copy large file and it failed?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWQUA.png this is the screenshot that i have tried.In here anyway i cannot copy the file.this is a CSV file and not a big file. I have tried to put a condition and its also failed.

Comment: Hi @Mishelle, why did you unmark the answer below ? May I know if you have any other concern about this question ? If still have any other concern about it, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 2):

For your problem, please refer to the logic I post below (I have upload a testcsv.csv file to the blob storage):

[image]

After the trigger "When a blob is added or modified", we need to use "Get blob content" action to get the content of the csv file. Then add "Create file" action of SharePoint and put the file content which we got from blob to the "File Content" box.

By the way, as you mentioned it is a csv file, so in my blob storage container I only have one file by default. If there are more than one file in your blob storage, you can use "List blobs" action and use "For each" to loop it and then create each of the file in SharePoint.

Answer (score 2):

I tried that however failed as it would not handle if you have folder structure in the blob and you'd like to mirror that structure in SP and copy individual files to folders.